# Azure CLI: Facing issue while creating datafactory trigger using JSOn

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-cli

Command to Create Trigger:
`az datafactory trigger create --factory-name test-factory-01 --resource-group ITS-TEST-RG --properties trigger.json --name stg2trans_accountspayable_erp_ap_trigger`

trigger.json file:

```
{
"properties": {
    "annotations": [],
    "runtimeState": "Stopped",
    "pipeline": {
        "pipelineReference": {
            "referenceName": "pipeline1_wf",
            "type": "PipelineReference"
        }
    },
    "type": "TumblingWindowTrigger",
    "typeProperties": {
        "frequency": "Hour",
        "interval": 24,
        "startTime": "2022-03-24T06:00:00Z",
        "delay": "00:00:00",
        "maxConcurrency": 50,
        "retryPolicy": {
            "intervalInSeconds": 30
        },
        "dependsOn": []
    }
}}
```

When running this code, it throws an error :
(InvalidTriggerType) Invalid trigger type: null

Code: InvalidTriggerType

Message: Invalid trigger type: null

Can someone help in resolving this issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution when I started analyzing the JSON formatting for Azure. I was passing the JSON as properties instead I should be passing it without properties. Basically here is what I mean to say:

```
{
"type": "TumblingWindowTrigger",
"typeProperties": {
    "frequency": "Hour",
    "interval": 24,
    "startTime": "2024-01-07T07:00:00Z",
    "delay": "00:00:00",
    "maxConcurrency": 1,
    "retryPolicy": {
        "count": 3,
        "intervalInSeconds": 60
    }
},
"dependsOn": [],
"pipeline": {
    "pipelineReference": {
        "referenceName": "pipeline1",
        "type": "PipelineReference"
    }
},
"runtimeState": "Stopped"
```

}

This JSON works and follows the right structure to be used in Azure CLI. The similar answer is posted here by @ritwikBojja

Answer (score 1):

The **`json`** which worked for me:

```
{
    "type": "TumblingWindowTrigger",
    "typeProperties": {
        "frequency": "Hour",
        "interval": 24,
        "startTime": "2024-02-08T00:00:00Z",
        "delay": "00:00:00"
    },
    "retryPolicy": {
        "intervalInSeconds": 30
    },
    "dependsOn": [],
    "properties": {
        "runtimeState": "Started",
        "pipelines": [
            {
                "pipelineReference": {
                    "type": "PipelineReference",
                    "referenceName": "myPipeline"
                },
                "parameters": {}
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Make sure to follow above correct json structure.

**`Azure CLI command:`**

```
az datafactory trigger create --resource-group 'testrg' --factory-name 'rith54' --name 'rithwiktrig' --properties @C:\Users\Downloads\rittest.json
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`In DataFactory:`**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The JSON file you provided is detailed properties for creating a "TumblingWindowTrigger" in Azure Data Factory, including its schedule, start time, concurrency settings, and retry policy.

On review of the JSON file, it appears that there are no formatting errors. The structure seems to be correct, with each property properly nested within its parent object.

My suggestion, you may want to try specifying the trigger type directly in the command rather than in the JSON file. Here's sample of how you can specify the trigger type directly in the code:

```
az datafactory trigger create --factory-name test-factory-01 --resource-group ITS-TEST-RG --name stg2trans_accountspayable_erp_ap_trigger --type TumblingWindowTrigger --properties @trigger.json
```

The code aboce, *--type TumblingWindowTrigger* explicitly specifies the trigger type, and *--properties @trigger.json* specifies the path to the JSON file containing trigger properties.

Modify to suit your configurations.

Let me know if you have more question.